# Call function from controller in view (panel)

Tags: extjs, controller

Hello i am want call function from controller in view (extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel'), i am want call function when press keyboard button but this not work
i am use this:

```
 this.getController('Book').createNew();
```

in console error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Views should not call functions, as it violates the whole point of MVC which is to have static, logic-less views and controllers to manage code execution.

Instead, you can create an event handler in your controller to listen for keyboard events from your view and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented a getController function in your panel?
If not you can use the one which is auto-generated the sencha build tool.

`MyAppName.app.getController(...);`

Where `MyAppName` is the name you define when you create your app using Ext.application.